# Formula to derive 'fiscal year' in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

ZP_TEST is a parameter field and it contains value 201210 - 201309 (BEx query selection variable)

From the above value we wanted to derive the fiscal year as 2013. Below is the formula that we have used but giving error.

`DateValue (Maximum ({?[ZP_TEST]}))`

Please correct the above formula if you see any mistake in it.

Comment: And what might that error be?

Comment: Error message is:"The special variable 'Formula' must be assigned a value within the formula"

Comment: You need to change from 'Basic Syntax' to 'Crystal Syntax'

Comment: Is the name of your parameter field really `[ZP_TEST]` or is it `ZP_TEST`?